# texImage2D is x1000 slower than usual

Tags: webgl

I'm creating a game that uses WebGL. Most of the time, everything is fine. However, for one particular call to gl.texImage2D with a 640x360 image, it takes 800ms rather than the usual 0.8ms.

What affects the performance of texImage2D?

All other gl.texImage2D with the same image size takes less than 1ms. The problematic gl.texImage2D is called after calling gl.texImage2D on a 100x100 texture.

Comment: What happens if you resize/or copy paste it the 640x360 image to a power of 2 dimension image?

Comment: I end up with the same bad performance. If I split it in 64x64 images, the browser crashes.

Comment: can you share some reproducible code?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem everytime but it requires my entire codebase. That's why my question on stackoverflow is only `What affects the performance of texImage2D?`.

Comment: It probably helps to create a small example and check if it still exists. This you can share.